# How to set the left inset on a TableView in iOS 7

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

Hi I am having trouble trying to set the inset on a table view cell for iOS 7, I have figured it out for iOS 8.

```
self.tableView?.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
self.tableView?.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
```

However this is only new to iOS 8.0 and I can't find the code to do this for iOS 7. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found an answer to this:

```
// Works with iOS 7
self.tableView?.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
```